# SQL Server export to Excel and MS Access in code

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

I need to write a stored procedure to take a filtered query (a select from a table) and create two files from it, an Excel file and an Access file. Although SQL Server has export for that, I need it in a query.

Is that possible through code? My boss wants me to automate this in SQL, that is why I'm not using 3rd party tools like StimulReport.

Any help or clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move data from SQL Server to MS Access mdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116465/move-data-from-sql-server-to-ms-access-mdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread is very similar to what you are requesting:

[Move data from SQL Server to MS Access mdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116465/move-data-from-sql-server-to-ms-access-mdb)

The key is the OpenDataSource command, there are examples of connections to Access and Excel sources in this link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856(v=sql.110).aspx