# Mapping columns in access to sql conversion

Tags: sql, ms-access, ssms

I have an access database that used 2 tables, a login table and then a data table that tied login id to the username in the login table. I'm needing to export just the data table to sql, which I can do fine. But what I'm running into is now I have a userid. Is there a way to pull up both an access table and a sql table and map the columns I want to match?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking. Perhaps you could clarify with some table definitions? What table has userid? Why can't you just export everything you need from Access over to MySQL?

Comment: I updated with a screenshot of the table with the data I need after running server migration assistant, but it has  loginID. There is a 2nd table in the access DB that ties username with that login id. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: In the past I've used a data warehouse software to do this sort of thing, but I'm not sure what software can be used for that now.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why you don't just migrate both Access tables over to SQL Server.  Does the login table need to stay in Access?  If it does, you can set up Access as a linked server.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9055695/4665459.  I'm removing the mysql tag as it doesn't appear that you're using it at all.

Comment: Because essentially I want to combine the 2 tables from access into 1 SQL table.

Comment: So migrate both tables from Access to MySQL as they are, then in MySQL create a table based on the two tables (`CREATE TABLE new_tbl AS  SELECT theColumnsYouWant FROM loginTable join dataTable on...;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I needed by migrating both of my tables to sql as they were, and then doing a select into statement joining the 2 on userid to get the username I wanted.