# Link SQL-Server tables to MS Access file

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

In my SQL Server database I need to mantain the tables linked and in sync with the tables of an MS Access .mdb file.

Lets say I update something or add something in the MS Access database via my own application.

I want those changes reflected in the SQL Server database.

I need a way to push the updates to the SQL Server database, or a way to update the SQL Server database with the new data when I connecto to it.

Trying to be clear: source must be the .mdb file database and destination must be the SQL server database. I need to keep them in sync.

Both databases have the same tables.

I have read a lot of posts, even this one: [From SQL Server how do I read from an MS Access database to UPDATE data in one or more table columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055444/from-sql-server-how-do-i-read-from-an-ms-access-database-to-update-data-in-one-o) that seems to be the solution, but I can figure out the steps.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (What done so far, describe your  application, Why do you need the mdb backend (e.g to work offline?), etc.).

Comment: Linking does not seem to be your problem. What you are looking for is synchronization between two tables. If a update or addition occurs sql side,  you need to update the  Access table. and if edits, deletes, and additions occur access side, you need these additions, deletions, and edits to make their way to sql server. This has very little to do with a linked table, but of having some kind of synchronization system that manages this issue and problem. You can google and perhaps adopt the .net sync framework, but your problem is far beyond a simple linked table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Albert. I will continue reading about your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The official tool for this is:

[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017)

It has a migration feature that, when run, will replicate (adjust) the table schema in the database in *SQL Server* to match that of the *Access* database.

Comment: It seem a solution. But the Migration tool takes a table in the MS Access File and links it to a table in the SQL Server.

So the MS Access database now uses a table stored in the SQL Server.

The problem is that my own application, built to work with the MS Access database, does not work now, trying to read the new table, modified by the migration tool.

Comment: It doesn't have to be so. The SSMA is quite configurable and doesn't have to modify the source database.

Comment: Yes @Gustav. As far as I konw if you need data sync, source tables are modified and **linked** to the SQL Server database. So the main app has problems to read or write that table.

Comment: Don't know. You cannot link an Access table to SQL Server (well, you can, using SSMS but that's another story). In Access you can link a table from SQL Server, but that doesn't impact Access tables you may have. Sounds like you haven't split the original database into a frontend and a backend. Migrate using the backend, and the frontend is left untouched.

Comment: I have my frontend app and a .mdb database.

If I link the tables in the .mdb database to the SQL server, the frontend app stops working, cause tables (structure or properties I suppose) have been modified in the original .mdb file to point to de SQL server.

Comment: Can't tell. A table is a table; it cannot be modified to point anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, @Gustav. Anyway the Migration Assistant is a great tool. And you have been a great help for me to understand some things and for continuing searching.

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend.